# Use sed to extract specific line from file?

Tags: bash, sed

I have for example this codes inside some file such as test.txt

```
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.mediafire.com/file/ke0f3n2u8sqbxsr/Ncam-Images-IPK.zip/file"
                        target="_blank"
                        rel="noopener"
                        id="copyShareURL"
                        class="nopop g-Icon g-Icon--white g-Icon--link"
                        aria-labelledby="copy-tooltip" title="Copy file link to clipboard"></a>
                    <span id="copy-tooltip" class="alt point-down tooltip">
                        Copy file link to clipboard
                    </span>
                </li>
    >
        <input type="hidden"
               name="security"
               value="1671208608.1b34b06f05dcee408eb015bfbc59436ab061fd4a21a61e3f970cd8d01f8ddcc3"
        >
        
        <div class="download_link" id="download_link">
    <!-- IF THIS IS TRADITIONAL -->
    <a class="preparing" href="#"><span>Preparing your download...</span></a>

            <a class="input popsok"
           aria-label="Download file"
           href="http://download2291.mediafire.com/h0k3ambdjvbg/ke0f3n2u8sqbxsr/Ncam-Images-IPK.zip"           id="downloadButton"
           rel="nofollow">
                Download (4.97MB)
        </a>
        <a class="starting" href="#"><span>Your download is starting...</span></a>
    <a class="retry" href="http://www.mediafire.com/download_repair.php?qkey=ke0f3n2u8sqbxsr&amp;dkey=h0k3ambdjvb&amp;template=34&amp;origin=click_button">
        <span class="notranslate">Download Started. <em>Repair your download</em></span>
    </a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     (function() {
         var dl = document.getElementById('download_link');
         if (!dl) return;
         var init = false;

         function retry() {
             dl.className += ' retry';
         };

         function download() {
             dl.className += ' started';
             window.dlStarted = true;
                             setTimeout(retry, 16000);
                      };
```

I need to extract this url line

```
http://download2291.mediafire.com/h0k3ambdjvbg/ke0f3n2u8sqbxsr/Ncam-Images-IPK.zip
```

P.s: the number after download(2291) and (h0k3ambdjvbg) string it is not fixed, but variable ..

I have use this command of sed but no result

```
sed -n 's|.*href="\(http://download.*\)">|\1|p' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
sed -n 's|.*href="\(http://download[^ "]*\)".*|\1|p' test.txt
```

to avoid matching quotes and spaces.

Answer (score 0):

With an HTML-aware tool such as [pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup), you could do something like

```
$ pup 'a.input attr{href}' < text.txt
http://download2291.mediafire.com/h0k3ambdjvbg/ke0f3n2u8sqbxsr/Ncam-Images-IPK.zip
```

assuming that the `input` class is unique enough to identify the URL you want.